# Do not get string in description content in regex

Tags: php, regex

Hello this is my string

```
/*
anything description
*/

Data1 = value1;

Other_Data = Other_Value;

/*
my other description
*/

Anything = Any_Answer;

/*

this is description and must not detect

Description_Data = Any_Value;

*/
```

now i want to use regex and get something like this

```
Data1
Other_Data
Anything
```

and

```
value1
Other_Value
Any_Answer
```

in array but i do not want regex detect anything inside of (description box)

```
/* */
```

like

```
Description_Data = Any_Value;
```

this is my regex

```
\h*(.*?)\h*[=]\h*(.*?)\h*[;]
```

my problem is that regex get all the keys and value even in description and in some keys, get everything before the key like all description before key ... i want to get just like this

```
Data1
Other_Data
Anything
```

and

```
value1
Other_Value
Any_Answer
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Do the keys and values consist of just alphanumerics and underscores?

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: update with my regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the keys and values consist of just alphanumerics and underscores.

You may skip the descriptions with the [SKIP-FAIL PCRE construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) and only match the key=value pairs that are at the beginning of a line with

```
(?m)\/\*[^*]*\*+([^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI6iK3/1)

The regex matches:

- `\/\*[^*]*\*+([^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches a multiline comment (**this pattern is written with the unroll-the-loop techique** and is quite efficient) and makes the regex engine discard the matched text and move the index to the end of this matched text (thus, we ignore the descriptions)
- `|` - or...
- `^\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)` - `^` matches the start of a line, then we match and capture into Group 1 (**the key**) one one or more word characters (with `(\w+)`), then just match zero or more whitespaces (`\s*`) followed with `=`, again zero or more whitespace symbols and then we capture into Group 2 (**the value**) one or more word characters.

The `(?sm)` are inline modifiers, you can just write them as `'~pattern-here~sm'`. The `s` is a *DOTALL* modifier making `.` match a newline. The `m` is a *MULTILINE* modifier making `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a *line*, not the whole string.

A variation for a more complex case when the keys and values can consist of any characters and the value trailing boundary is `;`+newline/end of string:

```
(?sm)\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*([^=\n]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?);\h*(?:$|\r?\n)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI6iK3/4)

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/RTv1C9):

```
$re = '~/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^/*][^*]*\*+)*/(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*([^=\n]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?);\h*(?:$|\r?\n)~sm'; 
$str = "/*\nanything description\n*/\n\nData1 = value1;\n\nOtherData<> = Other Value;\n\n/*\nmy other description\n*/\n\nAny thing = Any \nAnswer;\n\n/*\n\nthis is description and must not detect\n\nDescription_Data = Any_Value;\n\n*/"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
print_r($matches[2]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Data1
    [1] => OtherData<>
    [2] => Any thing
)
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => Other Value
    [2] => Any 
Answer
)
```

To also ignore full single-line comments (lines starting with `#`, `;` or `//`), you may add the `^\h*(?:\/\/|[#;])[^\n]*` alternative to SKIP-FAIL part:

```
(?sm)(?:^\h*(?:\/\/|[#;])[^\n]*|\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*([^=\n]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?);\h*(?:$|\r?\n)
```

See yet [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI6iK3/5). The `^\h*(?:\/\/|[#;])[^\n]*` matches the start of a line (with `^`), then either `//`, `#` or `;` and then zero or more characters other than newline (add `\r` if you have Mac OS line endings).

Comment: Can you explain more simple ?

Comment: The regexps skip all `/* ... */` and only grab keys and values into Group 1 and 2. Simple enough? :)

Comment: Can you say to me what should i do for # and // and ; (other description words) in one line ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to also skip single-line comments? If they occupy the whole line, just add the `^\h*(?:\/\/|[#;])[^\n]*` to the SKIP-FAIL part: [`(?sm)(?:^\h*(?:\/\/|[#;])[^\n]*|\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\/)(*SKIP)(*F)|^\s*([^=\n]+?)\s*=\s*(.*?);\h*(?:$|\r?\n)`](https://regex101.com/r/wI6iK3/5)

Comment: what is (?sm) in regex?

Comment: These are inline modifiers, you can just write them as `'~pattern-here~sm'`. `s` is a DOTALL modifier making `.` match a newline, too. `m` is a MULTILINE modifier making `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a *line*, not the whole string.